# Unable to use GNOME shell extension after installing chrome-gnome-shell

Tags: shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I followed the tutorial [here](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/) to install all the necessary packages to use gnome extensions on Firefox, Ubuntu 18.04. However, when I opened the website, it returned an error `Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.`

I double checked the chrome-gnome-shell, which returned `chrome-gnome-shell is already the newest version (10-1).`.

Is there any solution for this situation? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, but wrong site. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @David Yeah this would be a great question for Ask Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks! I will post this question on AskUbuntu

Comment: @David Actually, looks like it's already been asked: [URL extensions.gnome.org for managing GNOME Extensions not working in any browser](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034688/301745)

Comment: Good eye. That's points us to a good duplicate there `:)`

Answer (score 1):

go to chrome settings, then appearance. There in themes use GTK+ theme